# Restoring the Black Pearl - Ritual Question

Tags: plot-explanation, pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-men-tell-no-tales, on-stranger-tides

At end of *On Stranger Tides* Jack says to Gibbs that he needs an hourglass, trumpet, crossbow and three goats and he can perform counter-magic to restore the *Pearl*, but in *Dead Men Tell No Tales*,  Barbossa was able to restore by simply piercing the bottle.

So was Jack wrong about the ritual? And could anyone have pierced the bottle to restore the ship? Where are the other ships which Gibbs carried?

Is there any mention regarding the same in *Dead Men Tell No Tales* which I missed?

Comment: Jack is always funny with his dialogues

Comment: I agree with the first answer, but just to add, OST was loosely based on the novel of the same name and was actually optioned during COTBP, but passed on. Anyway, a theme of the novel was about ancient magical indigenous people and how other men have stolen the magic and corrupted it, and how there is not much left in the world to use (there is also a line in AWE between Jack and Barbosa that also reminds me of this). I know this scene is in part meant to be funny, but the "voodoo" finger-waving might wink back to it and other characters in POTC series such as Tia Dalma or Angelica.

Answer (score 2):

> So was Jack wrong about the ritual?

Possibly not. Though there is no mention of that ritual in the DMTNT, Jack couldn't possibly be wrong about the ritual.

Don't forget that Barbossa has the sword of Blackbeard, who apparently captured the Black Pearl in a bottle and the rest of the ships. Blackbeard did all the magic such as capturing ships with that sword and therefore, it is possible that that sword can also reverse it.

> could anyone have pierced the bottle to restore the ship?

Probably, yes, Anyone who has the sword of Blackbeard.

> Where are the other ships which Gibbs carried?

Though, I am not sure about this one as I have to watch the movie again for this. However, it's possible that he still has them kept somewhere.

Comment: The ritual was "a crossbow, an hourglass, three goats, one of [them] must learn to play the trumpet, whilst the other one goes like this" ('This' refers to motions similar to Jack's usual stagger)....so perhaps no-one learned to play the trumpet.